# Можно ли это тире использовать? По какому правилу?

Tags: тире

Можно ли это тире использовать? По какому правилу?

> Как бы мне ни было грустно, когда, уже разочарованный, я узнал, что больше у неё нет желания со мною встретиться, (—) мне пришлось всё-таки это принять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

***Как бы мне ни было грустно**, когда, уже разочарованный, я узнал, что больше у неё нет желания со мною встретиться, — **мне пришлось всё-таки это принять.***

**Пояснение**

**Сложное** предложение, 4 предикативные основы. Основная конструкция — СПП с придаточным **уступительным**, союзное слово ***КАК БЫ НИ***. Тире ставится по правилу Розенталя, учитывается **распространенность** придаточной части и наличие большого количества знаков. **Запятая** закрывает изъяснительную часть (союз ***ЧТО***).

Также возможно решение **методов блоков** по Лопатину, тогда ставим **единый знак**. Обозначает  повышение тона и подчеркнутую паузу.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142)**

Пункт 1. Тире ставится для **интонационного отделения** главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует:

3. придаточная **уступительная**: Пускай, как хотят, тиранят, пускай хоть кожу с живой снимут — я воли своей не отдам (С.‑Щ.); Сколько бы ни смотреть на море — оно никогда не надоест (Кат.).